# IBM MobileFirst 6.3 Firing Push Event Source Callback on app startup

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to know when it is recommended to call

```
WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback
```

and if the callback can be called when we open the app by tapping on a push notification while the application is closed.

When I check http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.Push.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-8
, I can read

> iOS and Android Registers a callback method that is called whenever a
>   notification arrives from the specified event source. If the
>   notification arrives while the application is not running, the mobile
>   OS starts the application at the specified callback

What I understand from here is that the application can call push notification callback on startup (while it was closed).

But when I check https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/, I can read

> If the application was in background mode (or inactive) when the push
>   notification arrived, this callback function is invoked when the
>   application returns to foreground.

and what I understand is that push callback will not be fired on startup.

Which page is correct, and if it is possible to call the event source callback on app startup, is there any sample doing that?

Comment: "and what I understand is that push callback will not be fired on startup.". I don't think that's correct. The link is saying that the callback function *is* invoked on startup. Why did you think it wasn't?

Comment: May be the conclusion is false, but the statement talks only about the case when the application is on background and returns to foreground. My question is concerning the case when the application is closed (not in background)

Comment: Fair point. Nevertheless, I think the behaviour is the same in both cases. I think that should be fairly quick to verify.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier I verified and I confirm that the behaviour is the same. What were confusing me is that the callback is not fired directly on startup but after authentication, which is the right way to do it.

Comment: that sounds like correct behaviour to me. You do need to be authenticated for the framework to validate that you are entitled to receive the push notification content - it's tied to a user, as well as a device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing and debugguing, I can confirm that it works fine even if the application is closed.
The event source callback is called after authentication.

Concerning my question when it is recommended to register callback function, it would be when the application is ready to subscribe for push, like in the sample provided by IBM:

```
if (WL.Client.Push) {   
    WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function() {
        alert("onReadyToSubscribe");

        WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
            "myPush", 
            "PushAdapter", 
            "PushEventSource", 
            pushNotificationReceived);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound conflicting to me.

When the app is closed, the callback is called on startup.
When the app is opened (in the background) and returns to the foreground, it's called when the app returns to the foreground.

Comment: in this case, when should we call WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback ? I tried to call it in wlCommonInit() but it does not work.

Comment: @idan Adar: is there a way to get an event when the app is closed/killed? I am sending an event whenever there is change in Internet Connectivity.